# How to return false instead of "TypeError: Cannot read property"?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a code that finds the value in A column and returns other column values in that row:

```
function getCurrentRow(e) {
  var parsedJson = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("List");

  var column = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  var values = column.getValues();
  var row = 0;

  while ( values[row] && values[row][0] !== parsedJson.myValue ) {
    row++;
  }

  if (values[row][0] === parsedJson.myValue) {
    var record = {};

    record['top'] = sheet.getRange((row+1), 2).getValue();
    record['bottom'] = sheet.getRange((row+1), 3).getValue();

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(record)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}
```

It works, but when it can't find myValue it returns

> TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined.

in this line:

```
if (values[row][0] === parsedJson.myValue) {
```

How can I fix that and return "Can't find myValue" instead?

Comment: What is the *complete* error message?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property &quot;0&quot; from undefined.

Comment: That means that `values[row]` is `undefined`

Comment: @Pointy, thank you for your answer. You are right. When there is no myValue in column A it can't find it and can't return the row number. But I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Well you perform a test in that `while` loop right before the `if` statement to check that `values[row]` exists; can't you just do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if (values[row][0] === parsedJson.myValue) {
```

should be

```
  if (values[row] && values[row][0] === parsedJson.myValue) {
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

While `values[row]` exists,  you're adding 1 to `row` with `row++`. Say, There are 5 rows(Index:0 to 4) in `A:A` and `values[row][0] !== parsedJson.myValue` in all 5 rows. At the final row(Actual row 5; Index:4), `row++` adds 1 and the `row` is now 5 (Index:5). But `values[5]`doesn't exist and is undefined, which has no `[0]` property.

#### Solution:

Add a another condition inside `while` condition:

```
var lastRowIndex = values.length;
while ( values[row] && 
values[row][0] !== parsedJson.myValue 
&& row < lastRowIndex ) {
 row++;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! I didn't think about that. But you made a small mistake: "adds 1 and the row is now 6 (Index:5)".

Comment: @Neret Actually the variable `row` is index. Actual row is 6, but `row`/index is 5. The variable name `row` could've been chosen better to avoid confusion, since it only denotes the index of the array and not the actual row number.